# wxpython dataray interface camera

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, activex, wxwidgets

I am currently trying modify the example given from the tutorial on this page That generates the GUI shown below. (You can download the example yourself on the second page of the tutorial).

[Tutorial](https://www.dataray.com/assets/pdf/Interfacing_DataRay_to_Python.pdf)

Running this code with Python 2.7 with wxPython and Comtypes will open a GUI similar to that on the last page of the tutorial that gives the properties of a beam of light.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.activex
import csv
import comtypes.client

class EventSink(object):

    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.counter = 0
        self.frame = frame

    def DataReady(self):
        self.counter +=1
        self.frame.Title= "DataReady fired {0} times".format(self.counter)


class MyApp( wx.App ): 

    def OnClick(self,e):
        rb_selection = self.rb.GetStringSelection()
        if rb_selection == "WinCam":
            data = self.gd.ctrl.GetWinCamDataAsVariant()
            data = [[x] for x in data]
        else:
            p_selection = self.cb.GetStringSelection()
            if p_selection == "Profile_X":
                data = self.px.ctrl.GetProfileDataAsVariant()
                data = [[x] for x in data]#csv.writerows accepts a list of rows where each row is a list, a list of lists
            elif p_selection == "Profile_Y":
                data = self.py.ctrl.GetProfileDataAsVariant()
                data = [[x] for x in data]
            else:
                datax = self.px.ctrl.GetProfileDataAsVariant()
                datay = self.py.ctrl.GetProfileDataAsVariant()
                data = [list(row) for row in zip(datax,datay)]#Makes a list of lists; X1 with Y1 in a list, X2 with Y2 in a list etc...
        filename = self.ti.Value
        with open(filename, 'wb') as fp:
            w = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
            w.writerows(data)

    def __init__( self, redirect=False, filename=None ):
        wx.App.__init__( self, redirect, filename )
        self.frame = wx.Frame( parent=None, id=wx.ID_ANY,size=(760,500), title='Python Interface to DataRay')
        #Panel
        p = wx.Panel(self.frame, wx.ID_ANY)
        #Get Data
        self.gd = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(p, 'DATARAYOCX.GetDataCtrl.1')
        #The methods of the object are available through the ctrl property of the item
        self.gd.ctrl.StartDriver()
        self.counter = 0
        sink = EventSink(self.frame)
        self.sink = comtypes.client.GetEvents(self.gd.ctrl, sink)
        #Button Panel
        bp = wx.Panel(parent=self.frame, id=wx.ID_ANY, size=(215, 250))
        b1 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(200,50), pos=(7, 0),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b1.ctrl.ButtonID =297 #Id's for some ActiveX controls must be set
        b2 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(100,25), pos=(5, 55),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b2.ctrl.ButtonID =171
        b3 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(100,25), pos=(110,55),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b3.ctrl.ButtonID =172
        b4 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(100,25), pos=(5, 85),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b4.ctrl.ButtonID =177
        b4 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(100,25), pos=(110, 85),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b4.ctrl.ButtonID =179
        #Custom controls
        t = wx.StaticText(bp, label="File:", pos=(5, 115))
        self.ti = wx.TextCtrl(bp, value="C:\Users\Public\Documents\output.csv", pos=(30, 115), size=(170, -1))
        self.rb = wx.RadioBox(bp, label="Data:", pos=(5, 140), choices=["Profile", "WinCam"])
        self.cb = wx.ComboBox(bp, pos=(5,200), choices=[ "Profile_X", "Profile_Y", "Both"])
        self.cb.SetSelection(0)
        myb = wx.Button(bp, label="Write", pos=(5,225))
        myb.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick)
        #Pictures
        pic = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=self.frame,size=(250,250),axID='DATARAYOCX.CCDimageCtrl.1')
        tpic = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=self.frame,size=(250,250), axID='DATARAYOCX.ThreeDviewCtrl.1')
        palette = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=self.frame,size=(10,250), axID='DATARAYOCX.PaletteBarCtrl.1')
        #Profiles
        self.px = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=self.frame,size=(300,200),axID='DATARAYOCX.ProfilesCtrl.1')
        self.px.ctrl.ProfileID=22
        self.py = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=self.frame,size=(300,200),axID='DATARAYOCX.ProfilesCtrl.1')
        self.py.ctrl.ProfileID = 23
        #Formatting 
        row1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        row1.Add(item=bp,flag=wx.RIGHT, border=10)
        row1.Add(pic)
        row1.Add(item=tpic, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)
        row2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        row2.Add(self.px, 0, wx.RIGHT, 100)# Arguments: item, proportion, flags, border
        row2.Add(self.py)
        col1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        col1.Add(item=row1, flag=wx.BOTTOM, border=10)
        col1.Add(item=row2, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
        self.frame.SetSizer(col1)
        self.frame.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = MyApp()
     app.MainLoop()
```

Essentially, my goal is to extract the data from the buttons and either write it to a file or compile it as a list, but I have no idea what command to use to access that data.

I know most people don't have access to the hardware I am using, but my question is more focused on the wxPython controls with buttons, and how to get that data.

If it helps, here is the documentation of the OCX controls with the camera.

[DataRay OCX Documentation](https://www.dataray.com/assets/pdf/OCXDocumentation.pdf)

Let me know if there is question I can answer. Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to docs it should return a double value with the contents with e.g. `b1.ctrl.GetParameter()` for button `b1`.

This of course requires to store the button objects, e.g. in the `MyApp` object.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! using the GetParameter() method is indeed helpful. I am a little lost on your second however. Is the MyApp class not the same as the object? If not, what is the MyApp object and what do I need to do move the buttons withing that object?

Comment: @Jgold247 It is enough to assign the button objects to something like `self.b1`. So they can be used in other methods of the class in the same way as `self.b1`. For details about classes and objects read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html